# Неадекватно работает BETWEEN с цифрами в MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Пытаюсь получить данные в БД (MySQL) через **BETWEEN**

Если я хочу получить от **0** до **99**, то он все находит. А как только пытаюсь получить от **5** до **99**, то ничего не находит.

**Так он находит:**

`` SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'home_c_bedrooms' AND `meta_value` BETWEEN '0' AND '99' ``

[image: Рабочий код]

**А так не работает:**

`` SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'home_c_bedrooms' AND `meta_value` BETWEEN '5' AND '99' ``

[image: Не рабочий вариант]

Comment: `'0'` - это не число, это строковый литерал, поэтому сравнение идет в алфавитном порядке. Уберите кавычки и будет число.

Comment: Какие ещё "цифры"? Или число, или строка. У тебя все три параметра - строка, соответственно и контекст строковый, а не числовой.

Comment: Да, это сработало. Но вот в коде wp php meta_query когда я пытаюсь добавить диапазон он не работает.